# Alternative HTML Scraping Function?

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I am a novice programmer in the process of creating a web scraping program that will accelerate the conversion of .ict files from NASA's EarthData Database to .csv files for programming use.

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe from the .ict file stored at this URL:
https://asdc.larc.nasa.gov/data/AJAX/O3_1/2018/06/06/AJAX-O3_ALPHA_20180606_R1_F229.ict

and planned on using the `BeautifulSoup` library to scrape the data. When I coded the `soup.findAll` function, I realized that it returned the entire dataframe as it is nested in one paragraph of HTML code. I think that since all of the data is stored in one paragraph, it makes the `findAll` function difficult to use.

Is there an alternate library that I can use in order to get the data I am looking for? Here is some code that successfully returns the HTML for the file I am attempting to scrape:

```
html_data = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

This returns the data:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
[42 lines of metadata text]
Int_Start, Int_End, TIME, G_Lat, G_Lon, G_Alt, O3
      72073.0,      72081.0,      72077.4,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      34.8884
      72084.0,      72092.0,      72087.6,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      33.0842
      72093.0,      72101.0,      72097.4,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      33.0454
      72104.0,      72112.0,      72107.6,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      -9999.0000,      34.7138
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Interestingly, the data is not stored as a table, as the code

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

dfs = pd.read_html(page.text)
```

presents an error that no tables are found.  Any advice that could be used to help me circumvent this problem would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the directory for the file you shared, and I noticed this link, [Scripts for Downloading Data](https://forum.earthdata.nasa.gov/viewforum.php?f=7&&DAAC=1&ServicesUsage=15,16&sid=f932e54447fc94fe2fd8caee06998b71).

From there I clicked on [Downloading ASDC Data with Python 3](https://forum.earthdata.nasa.gov/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2330&sid=f932e54447fc94fe2fd8caee06998b71) and there are two scripts; one for downloading an individual ICT file, and the second for downloading a directory tree of ICT files.

I'd start with the second script, and see if you can get all your ICT files downloaded.

Once you have the ICT files, the next step will be to get them to CSV, which isn't easy, and since you've admitted you're a novice, I'd defer to software that's already written.  I could not find a tool for directly converting ICT (called "ICARTT") to CSV. I did find [a tool for converting from ICT to NetCDF](https://github.com/jjmcnelis/ornldaac_icartt_to_netcdf), and once it's in NetCDF, you can export to CSV.